# Change iframe size after clicking a content inside an iframe in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, iframe

Good day all, I'm trying to make a website where user have to login from another website and that part is on an iframe. What I want is when user click on `Login` button, iframe will resize itself to see only the specific content of that website. Here is my code,

```
<div id="reportframe" style="margin: auto;">
        <iframe src="http://www.abcdsebroker.com/login" width="600" height="400"></iframe>
</div>
```

**This is the asp.net webform code for the Login button in other website,**

```
<div class="control-group text-center">
    <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="50%" Font-Bold="true" Text="Login" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="btnlogin_Click" />
</div>
```

How can I change the size of iframe after clicking Login button using jQuery? Your help would be much appreciable. Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

SET id for Iframe.

```
     <div id="reportframe" style="margin: auto;">
                    <iframe id="ifreportframe" src="http://www.abcdsebroker.com/login" width="600" height="400"></iframe>
            </div> 
            <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Height="35px" Width="50%" Font-Bold="true" Text="Login" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="btnlogin_Click"  onClientClick="resizeIframe()"/>

            <script>
             function resizeIframe()
            {
              $("#ifreportframe").css("height","500px");
              $("#ifreportframe").css("width","700px")
            }
            </script>
```

Comment: The `Login` button is from another website, Will `resizeIframe()` work from my website script?